# Illegal type offset

Tags: php, arrays

Hello i am having an array in php that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [english] => Array
        (
            [0] => save
            [1] => sign in
            [2] => forgot password?
            [3] => customer area
            [4] => password
            [5] => sign in to get access to the dashboard
            [6] => your credentials are incorrect. please try again.
            [7] => my information
        )

    [german] => Array
        (
            [0] => sparen
            [1] => anmelden
            [2] => passwort vergessen?
            [3] => kundenbereich
            [4] => passwort
            [5] => meine daten
            [6] => dashboard
            [7] => mitreisende
        )
)
```

From which i want to populate a table. My code:

```
<tbody>
    <?php foreach ($arrmerged as $key => $value) {

            echo $arrmerged['english'][$value];?>
    <tr class="odd" role="row">
        <td class="sorting_1"><?=$arrmerged['english'][$value];?></td>
        <td><?=$arrmerged['german'][$value];?></td>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button></td>
    </tr>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
</tbody>
```

But i get this error:

```
Warning: Illegal offset type
```

I have tried `$value = new stdClass();`

but still the same error. How can i populate 1 column of the table with english array and another column with german array. Any help will be appreaciated!!!

Comment: is the array hardcoded ?

Comment: You know, that the german translation isn't equal to the english part?

Comment: `$value` is an array. `$arrmerged['english'][array()]` is 1) nonsensical and 2) an *illegal offset type*.

Comment: You have to access the `$key` part and not the `$value` part: $arrmerged['english'][$key] to get the value.

Comment: Are you trying to loop over `foreach ($arrmerged['english'] as $key => $value)`...?!

Comment: yes the array is hardcoded (the values are not coming from any database), 2) yes i know that the translation is not equal but its not all the data its part of data, 3) @deceze what exactly is nonsensical?

Comment: That you're trying to use an `array(...)` *as array index* is nonsensical.

Comment: Just `var_dump($value)` to see what `$value` in `$arrmerged['english'][$value]` is and you'll agree that it's nonsensical.

Comment: i tried `$arrmerged['english'][$key]` and now i get `Undefined index: english`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use for loop on your main array

and print each index at each row for both languages

but first you need to find how many total words you are having in the language array.

```
<?php $total_words = count($arrmerged['english']);
  for($i=0; $i<$total_words; $i++)
  { ?>

    <tr class="odd" role="row">
        <td><?=$arrmerged['english'][$i];?></td>
        <td><?=$arrmerged['german'][$i];?></td>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button></td>
    </tr> 
<?php } ?>
```

and this will do the magic for you.

Comment: but there is a small problemm. I get duplicate lines

Comment: i don't think the above code should print duplicate entries, check if there is any other non-required loop involved in the code or if you retrieving data from db then db is sending the correct values.

Comment: no its not it was my fault...thanks again... but i am having this values populated from a file that i read. Is it difficult to edit them and saved them again in the file?

Answer (score 0):

Add more more level of foreach loop for $value variable...

```
foreach ($arrmerged as $key => $value)
```

Here

$arrmerged holds your main array

$key contains english, German

and

$value contains

```
        [0] => sparen

        [1] => anmelden

        [2] => passwort vergessen?

        [3] => kundenbereich

        [4] => passwort

        [5] => meine daten

        [6] => dashboard

        [7] => mitreisende
```

Answer (score 0):

Use two level [`foreach()`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

```
<tbody>
<?php foreach ($arrmerged as $key => $value) {

       echo $key; // this will print english and germany
       foreach ($value as $k => $val) {
         //print the values for english
         if ($key == 'english') {?>
           <tr class="odd" role="row">
           <td class="sorting_1"><?=$val;?></td><? } 
         else {?>
           //print the values for germany
           <td><?=$val;?></td>
           <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button></td>
        <? } ?>
    </tr>
  </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: this prints everything in 1 column and it messes up the table